# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity error after changing package name

Tags: java, android

So I've developed an app, wanted to upload it to the play store, but when it said i had to change the package name different from com.example.app_name I changed it.
But now I'm getting an error:

```
    05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3034)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     ... 11 more
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.gip.icomplain.Home.getGPSLocation(Home.java:209)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.gip.icomplain.Home.send(Home.java:130)
05-29 22:35:15.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     ... 14 more
```

here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvFoto);
        onderwerp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);
        commentaar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtComment);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }
    public void getGPSLocation() {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());
        currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (currentLocation != null) {
            longitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            latitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
        }
        EXTRA_TEXT = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    }
}
```

Please help, this is very important!!!!

Comment: Did you chang the package name inside the ANdroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes I did,
I think it has something to do with my locationManager

Comment: If you use eclipse, you can use `refractor` to rename. It will take care of changes in each fie if required.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, that's `Refactor`.

Comment: @HelderJulesDeBaere, where's your NPE? Is it possible you were using Mock Locations in testing?

Comment: I did that actually...

Comment: @323go yes, I was but I tested it on a real device, same problem...

Comment: So, where's your NullPointerException? Find out what's null, and your problem will likely solve itself :)

Comment: locationManager is the null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a NullPointerException at your `getGPSLocation`, in your `locationManager` here:

```
if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
}
```

You should remove the re-declaration of `locationManager` (removing the type `LocationManager`) both in `onCreate` and in `getGPSLocation`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Instead of: 
// LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
...
}
```

and

```
public void getGPSLocation() {
...
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Instead of: 
// LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
...
}
```

BTW, you should also check for a null value of locationmanager before every

`if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){`

Answer (score 1):

You have locationManager as class member but redeclare it inside the onCreate. This way you hide the memeber class and it is never initialized.

Then in getGpsLocation() you use it this way:

```
public void getGPSLocation() {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
```

remove `LocationManager` from onCreate

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: omfg, thank you so much!
can't thumb you up, no 15 rep...
If I could i would give you a thousand, you saved my butt here!

Comment: As I say in my answer, you should also remove it from `getGPSlocation` as it is also hiding the member class.

Comment: I've been here a while, but haven't answered any other's problems (: